# Add uuid4 large integer to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a large integer into a file.

The file contains an ID which is 8bytes long - I want to write a new random ID into the file. I am using uuid4 to generate a random number which looks right, but is very big.

```
new_id = str(uuid.uuid4().int>>64) # generate a 64bit ID.
foo = fi.read() # read current file
bar = re.search(b'MyOLDID', foo) # search for value
fi.seek(bar.start())
old_id = fi.read(8)
new_id = uuid.uuid4().int>>64 # generate ID.    
faz = foo.replace(bytes(old_id), new_id)
```

How do I replace the old id with the new one?

Comment: Not sure what you want...do you want a way to generate an 8 byte random integer, or do you want to know how to save the UUID to a file?

Comment: I want to generate random & replace 8 bytes of ID in the file 'fi'. foo is bytes, and I can find my old_id and where it starts - when I try to convert the integer new_id to bytes to write to the file I get a memory error because it is a big integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.urandom` to get random bytes:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.urandom(8)
Out[2]: b'\xe2\xf4~_n.\xe0X'
```

(example from an IPython session)

If you want readable characters, encode the random data with e.g. base64.

```
In [3]: import base64

In [4]: base64.b64encode(os.urandom(6))
Out[4]: b'NeCBB8jF'
```

The encoding process makes the data longer, so you only need 6 bytes in this case.

If you need digits:

```
In [5]: ''.join(str(j) for j in os.urandom(4))[:8]
Out[5]: '22310824'
```

Comment: This is very useful to me thanks - I was also experimenting with the last idea here, but ended up writing 8 random bytes directly to the file as in the first example.